# Clicking calendar button not working on Angular UI datepicker inside accordion

Tags: javascript, angularjs, calendar, datepicker, accordion

Here is a plunker http://plnkr.co/edit/2Fs6vCciXRRc7GeUwyR2?p=preview

Is anyone could help to advise why the calendar button is not working?
However clicking the calendar textbox showing calendarpopup just fine.

It seems that scope.$watch('isOpen', function(value) { ... }
not working anymore when datepicker is inside accordion and using calendar button.

many thanks in advance,

Ferry

Comment: Welcome on SO! What did you do to solve your problem? And please show us you code.

Comment: He looks to have his code in plunkr @smartmeta

Comment: I did look at this but don't have a solution yet, it seems that 1) you should be using is-open=, not open=, and 2) The control seems to take over the variable, not sure how to update it just yet, most people suggest using the AngularStrap plugin, if I solve this I'll come back and post.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There was one issue in your plunker - as noticed by @Daniel Dawes you need to use `is-open` instead `open`, as documented: http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/datepicker

Then, the problem of the calendar being cut off in the last accordion is due to the Bootstrap CSS. You can around this by using the `datepicker-append-to-body="true"` attribute.

Working plunk here: http://plnkr.co/edit/3d3CX25eNbUvv5U8qiV8?p=preview

Comment: I think I know my mistake. I was using the same Ctrl for both Accordion and Datepicker. After I separate it works! many thanks for all your help

Comment: You made my day :) Thanks a lot (Y)